# Adding dependency to an existing assembleDebug Task

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradlew

My tasks look like this, I have a build type as assembleDebugDaily. I am trying to run Task dailyCiBuild

```
task versionGitTagBuild() {
    doLast {
        println "Versioning git tag build finished"
    }

}
task zipAlignAPK(){
    doLast{
        println "ZipAlign Completed"
    }
}
tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (task.name == 'assembleDebugDaily') {
        task.mustRunAfter versionGitTagBuild //*This line is the problem*
        zipAlignAPK.dependsOn(task)
    }
}
task copyToBuildShare(){
        dependsOn zipAlignAPK
        doLast {
            println("Finished")

        }
}
task dailyCiBuild(){
    dependsOn copyToBuildShare
    doLast{
        println "CI Build Finished"
    }
}
```

It always results in stackOverflow error. If I remove the indicated line above. It builds successfully. What am i doing wrong and how to achieve the above functionality ?

Comment: Can you post the stackoverflow error?